# Use Template Input Variables outside of NgFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

A common well familiar case:

```
<div *ngFor="let hero of heroes$ |async">
  <span>{{hero.name}}</span>
</div>
```

My question is how to have the same behavior when `heroes` is not an Observable of an array of `Hero`s, but an Observable of singular Heros

```
<div *???="let hero of hero$ |async">
  <span>{{hero.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: No need to iterate just `<span>{{(hero$ | async)?.name}}</span>`

Comment: what happens if I have 15 properties in Hero class? Subscribe 15 times to the observable?

Comment: `<div *ngIf="(hero$ | async) as hero">{{hero.name}}{{hero.id}}{{hero.something}}</div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use a `*ngFor` directive to parse a single object rather use an variable to assign the async property to it and use that substitute variable inside as

```
<ng-container *ngIf="hero$ | async as hero">
    {{hero.name}}
</ng-container>
```

A working example at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-async-pipe-with-ngif-else